# Roslyn create custom expression

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, roslyn, c#-7.0

I'm playing with roslyn generation and it works fine except when it doesn't. For example, I'd like to use C# 7.0 feature `throw expression`. But I don't see any corresponding method in `SyntaxFactory`.

Is it possible now to generate something like `var foo = bar ?? throw new Exception();`? Because NullCoalesceExpression expexts `ExpressionSyntax`, while `ThrowStatement` is obviosly a statement.

I have tried to build it from scratch (that's what I mean under `custom expression`), but i'm only getting multiple exceptions `Unexpected SyntaxKind`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it doesn't make much sense to create "custom expressions" with Roslyn. Roslyn is the C# compiler, so it always has to accurately represent all C# syntax.

That being said, if you want to create a syntax node from a string, you do have some options in the form of `SyntaxFactory.Parse*` methods. In your case, it would be [`SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/2.2.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory/ParseExpression(System.String,System.Int32,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ParseOptions,System.Boolean)).

As for `throw` expressions, they of course have their own `SyntaxFactory` method: [`SyntaxFactory.ThrowExpression`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/2.2.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory/ThrowExpression(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ExpressionSyntax)). Just make sure you're using an up-to-date version of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` (at least 2.0.0).

Also, if you want to know how to build certain code using the Roslyn API, [Roslyn Quoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) can be very useful.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but this `quoter` is just awesome. I wasn't aware that something similar even can exist! It's really handful. Waiting for a new day to try all this stuff.

Comment: Roslyn Quoter saved my sanity!!!  It is very helpful!